# PHP/Apache timing out too early

Tags: php, apache, timeout

I have a program which submits a post request of about 1.8MB in size to a PHP script which converts the data into an image.

Unfortunately, for some reason the server has recently started rejecting larger post requests, while still accepting smaller ones.

I've gone over every setting, but I can't seem to find the issue.

The post request is timing out at exactly 20 seconds every time, even though it shouldn't be timing out until 60 seconds.

```
max_input_time: 60
upload_max_filesize: 10M
post_max_size: 8M

Timeout: 300

Post request timeout in vb program: 60000 (60 seconds)
```

Example of a failed request: [imgur.com/qx1iW,LV9OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT5WP.png)

Example of a successful request: [imgur.com/qx1iW,LV9OS#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT5WP.png#1)

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Where you set? `php.ini` or `yourfile.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the property in `php.ini` which says:

```
max_execution_time: 60; # in seconds
```

Comment: max_execution_time is already set to 60, sorry. Forgot to include that.